# How could I create a <ul> element for each post

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, format

```js
[
  {
    title: "title of post"
    author: "some guy"
  },
  {
    title: "title of post",
    author: "some guy"
  }
]
```

When a user searches for an article, it might return something like the above. How could I make, using VanillaJS or jQuery, it return a page with a `<ul>` tag with `<li>` tags for the data inside for the title and author? I know this is a big question, but I don't need an exact answer, just an idea of what to do! I also tried foreach but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks,
Jude Wilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you're trying to create a `<ul>` tag that has many children `<li>` tags each containing the filtered data `title`, and `author` keys.

Well normally I recommend using something like vue.js to manage data bindings for your UI, but since you mentioned you want this accomplished using jQuery or vanilla JS, it's rather simple than you think.

Here is a complete HTML code example, using jQuery:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- Posts List Container -->
        <div>
            <ul id="postsContainer"></ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Post Template (Just an example use-case) -->
        <template id="postTemplate">
            <li class="post-meta-data">
                <h2 class="post-title"></h2>
                <strong class="post-author"></strong>
                <em class="post-tags"></em>
            </li>
        </template>

        <!-- Include jQuery -->
        <script 
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- Our JS Logic -->
        <script>
            $(function () {
                const
                $container = $('#postsContainer'),

                // Grabs the HTML content of the "tag" template
                template = $('#postTemplate').html(),

                // Here you can fetch/return your API's or filtered data
                // NOTE: I modified the data to showcase the example.
                getData = () => {
                    return [
                        {
                            title: "title of post #1",
                            author: "some guy",
                            tags: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
                        },
                        {
                            title: "title of post #2",
                            author: "some other guy",
                            tags: ['watermelon', 'apple', 'banana'],
                        }
                    ];
                },
                
                // Here you can call this function to update the UI 
                // based on the data returned by "getData()"
                updateSearchTags = () => {
                    const postsArray = getData();

                    // Before adding any new elements to the container, we should empty it first.
                    $container.empty();

                    for (const post of postsArray) {
                        const 
                        { title, author, tags } = post,
                        $postEl = $(template);

                        // Hydrate the template with post data
                        $postEl.find('.post-title').text(title);
                        $postEl.find('.post-author').text(author);
                        $postEl.find('.post-tags').text(tags.join(', '));

                        // Add the post element to the list
                        $postEl.appendTo($container);
                    }
                };

                // Call the UI Update Function whenever necessary
                updateSearchTags();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to play around with a bit for it to adopt to my setup but it ended up working!

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what you mean by "return a page" but you could `map` over the data and set it to the `ul` with `innerHTML`

```js
function printData(ele, data) {
  ele.innerHTML = data.map(item => `<li>${item.title} - ${item.author}</li>`).join('')
}

const ulEle = document.querySelector('#target')
const data = [
  { title: "title of post", author: "some guy" },
  { title: "title of post", author: "some guy" }
]

printData(ulEle, data)
```

```html
<ul id="target"></ul>
```